# QField zoom in/out with camera

Tags: qfield

We are using QField on a Windows tablet.
We can zoom perfectly fine with the Windows camera app but can't zoom in/out in the QField camera.

It doesnt look like there is a "use native camera" option in QField Windows version.

Is there something we can do/try?